# Flexbox разделение по сторонам

Tags: css, flexbox

Вопрос такой, на flex если использовать justify-content: space-between;  необходимо чтобы средний блок прижимался к левому краю. Подробнее в примере:

```css
.flex {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  height: 120px;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}   
.block {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="block"> </div>
  <div class="block"> Этот блок должен прижаться к левому </div>
  <div class="block"> а этот остаться на месте </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `margin-right:auto`

```css
.flex {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  height: 120px;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 120px;
}

.block:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block">Этот блок должен прижаться к левому</div>
  <div class="block">а этот остаться на месте </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Использовать `flex` вместе с `margin: auto` - костыль, не считаете?

Comment: Не считаю. Поведение автоматического `margin` определяется в спецификации для `flexible layout module`.

Comment: Тогда беру свой минус обратно) Допишите в ответ, смогу минус убрать

Comment: Что в ответ дописать? Вот ссылка на пример, чтобы не быть голословным https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins

Comment: Да, я нашёл. SO запрещает мне сменить голос, пока ответ не отредактирован

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.flex>div+div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.flex>div:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>left</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: тут css-препроцессоры не работают. А код лучше вставлять/писать в сниппет. В редакторе есть соответствующая кнопка (либо `Ctrl+M`).

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

Для разнесения элементов по разным сторонам при использовании `display: flex` есть специальное свойство `justify-content: space-between`.

Пример:

```css
#example {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
#example > .element {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "example">
  <div class = "element"></div>
  
  <div class = "element"></div>
</div>
```

Ссылки:

0. [Документация W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#valdef-align-content-space-between).
1. [Документацию MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
2. [Руководство по flexbox-ам](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).